# Retrieve count of total no of answers corresponding to each tag at user level

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am trying to create a query, to find the count of total number of answers (that I have give in stackoverflow) corresponding to each tag.

Through [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i), I am able to find total count of my accepted, scored and unscored answers.

And using [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag), I am able to find how many upvotes do I have of each tag.

I ran the below query in the [data.StackExcange](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) to get the desired result, but I did not succeed.

This is my query:

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT --TOP 20 
    TagName,
    count(a.Id) as [Accepted Answers]
from
    Posts q
  inner join
    Posts a
  on a.Id = q.AcceptedAnswerId

WHERE 
    Posts.OwnerUserId = @UserId
    a.CommunityOwnedDate is null
  and a.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
  and q.OwnerUserId != ##UserId##
  and a.postTypeId = 2
GROUP BY TagName
```

**Update 1:**

**I also have to find url of the questions, title and all the other tags corresponding to that answer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query finds the total number of answers against each tag for a user. It does not consider the self-answered questions of the user, as it can give little additional count.

```sql
--Self answered questions dont count
select t.TagName, COUNT(q.Id) as countofAnsweredQuestions
from Posts q
inner join PostTags AS pt
ON pt.PostId = q.Id
inner join Posts a
on a.parentId = q.Id
inner join Tags as t
on pt.tagId = t.Id
where q.CommunityOwnedDate is null and q.ClosedDate is null 
  and a.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
  and q.OwnerUserId != ##UserId##
  and a.postTypeId = 2
GROUP BY t.TagName
ORDER BY countofAnsweredQuestions desc
```

I have created [permanent link for the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1217041/retrieve-count-of-total-no-of-answers-corresponding-to-each-tag-at-user-level?UserId=634935)

Comment: this query is working, but I want to find the total no. of answers which I have given in SO, corresponding to each tag.

Comment: From your query. I am getting the total count of unanswered questions(of SO) corresponding to each tag

Comment: you did not mention that you want at user level

Comment: Originally, it was asked as count. If you want separate information, ask as a separate question. keep updating question, will lead to confusion

Comment: can you please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60970531/find-the-post-link-related-tags-corresponding-to-each-tag-and-answer-at-user-le

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the `COUNT()` of your *accepted answers* for each tag then

```
SELECT T.TagName, COUNT(Q.Id) CntAcceptedAnswer
FROM Posts Q
JOIN PostTags PT ON Q.Id = PT.PostId
JOIN Tags T ON T.Id = PT.TagId
JOIN Posts A ON Q.AcceptedAnswerId = A.Id
WHERE A.OwnerUserId = <YourUserId>
      AND A.PostTypeId = 2
      AND Q.ClosedDate IS NULL
      AND Q.DeletionDate IS NULL
GROUP BY T.TagName;
```

If you're looking for all your answers for each tag then

```
SELECT T.TagName, COUNT(A.Id) Cnt
FROM Posts A 
JOIN Posts Q ON Q.Id = A.ParentId
JOIN PostTags PT ON Q.Id = PT.PostId
JOIN Tags T ON T.Id = PT.TagId
WHERE A.OwnerUserId = <YourUserId>
-- You can filter closed and deleted posts here as well if needed
GROUP BY T.TagName;
```

UPDATE:

For your update

> I also need to find url of the questions, title and all the other tags related to that answer.

You could use the query as a subquery and join it with `Posts` table to get the other columns as well.

Comment: Can you please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60970531/find-the-post-link-related-tags-corresponding-to-each-tag-and-answer-at-user-le