# Find how many upvotes I have on each answer corresponding to a particular tag at user level

Tags: sql, sql-server

In continuation of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60970531/find-the-post-link-related-tags-corresponding-to-each-tag-and-answer-at-user-le)

I am able to get the post link, title and count of the answers corresponding to a particular tag at the user level using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1217663?UserId=10348758), through which I get

[image]

**Now, I am trying to find the number of upvotes I have of the answer, corresponding to a particular tag at user level.**

I ran the below query in [data.stackexchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new), to get the desired result, but I did not succeed.

[This is the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1217675?UserId=10348758)

```
DECLARE @UserID int = ##UserID:int##;
SELECT DISTINCT T.TagName,
       COUNT(A.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Id) AS AnswersInTag,
       Q.Title,
       COUNT(*) AS UpVotes,
       CONCAT('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',Q.ID,'/') AS URL
FROM dbo.Posts Q
     JOIN dbo.Posts A ON Q.Id = A.ParentID
     JOIN PostTags PT ON Q.Id = PT.PostId
     JOIN Tags T ON T.Id = PT.TagId
     JOIN Votes ON Votes.PostId = A.Id and VoteTypeId = 2
WHERE A.OwnerUserID = @UserID AND
T.TagName='elasticsearch-query';
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue ?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Because there isn't a question.  This should stand-alone with references though a bunch of links -- with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am using SEDE https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60967044/2029983) and [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60970531/2029983).

Comment: @Bhavya it's helpful if you link to the query you made, not the new query editor. (Like I told you in the last question.)

Comment: @Larnu ok I will update my question

Comment: What about the query you wrote "didn't work"? I assume it's because you are creating a many to many join (on answers in the tag and votes on said answer) but counting them the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another guess, but perhaps...

```
DECLARE @UserID int = ##UserID:int##;
SELECT DISTINCT T.TagName,
       COUNT(A.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Id) AS AnswersInTag,
       Q.Title,
       SUM(V.Upvotes) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Id) AS UpVotesInTag,
       CONCAT('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',Q.ID,'/') AS URL
FROM dbo.Posts Q
     JOIN dbo.Posts A ON Q.Id = A.ParentID
     JOIN PostTags PT ON Q.Id = PT.PostId
     JOIN Tags T ON T.Id = PT.TagId
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS UpVotes
                  FROM dbo.Votes V
                  WHERE V.PostId = A.Id
                    AND V.VoteTypeId = 2) V
WHERE A.OwnerUserID = @UserID
ORDER BY UpVotesInTag DESC;
```

[SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1217678?UserId=10348758)

I do suggest taking the time to learn the model of the Stack Exchange databases, if you're going to be querying it. The problem(s) appear to be stemming from your lack of knowledge of it, however, it's quite a simple design to learn, if you take the time to learn it.

Comment: But I want to find count of upvotes on a particular answer, and not the count of upvotes on the tag

Comment: Then remove the `SUM` and just reference the value of `Upvotes` @Bhavya ... You should understand the SQL enough to do that.

Comment: Replacing `T.Id` with `Q.Id` in the `SUM` , gave me my required result

Comment: That's not what I said @Bhavya . Just remove the `SUM`... Reference the column itself.

Comment: Okay, will do that